# Custom js select dropdown option does not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, dropdown

I try to use a custom dropdown which works properly. But when I click on an option in the custom dropdown, the option was not changed in the original dropdown. The script only changes the placeholder.

I tried with the method of [JAG](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/07/10/inspiration-for-custom-select-elements/comment-page-4/):

added an ID attribute to line 138 in the selectFx.js

```js
var opts_el = "+ options +";

(function($) {
  $('#Lista li').click(function() {
    var texto = $(this).data('value');

    $('#Selectelement option').filter(function() {
      return this.value == texto;
    }).prop("selected", true).change();
  });
})(JQuery);
```

But I can not integrate the code, I get syntax errors.

**Edit : Added Jsfiddle ! Thank you for your reply ! I create an example here**

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/unicode1/1qquv1ft/7/)

Comment: The code you posted has spaces in many places that it shouldn't... ie... syntax errors

Comment: place the entire code or a jsfiddle

Comment: The fiddle code you provided works well.

Comment: Thanks Mojtaba. But the alert does not work when you change the option with the custom drop-down menu.